# ?action= delete from url with RewriteRule Htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Given a url such as

```
domain.com/?action=param
```

I want to delete the       `?action=`     from the url.

I thought to solve it with the following rewrite rule

```
  RewriteRule ^$ /?action=$1
```

or

```
  RewriteRule ^(.*) /?action=$1
```

However, this did not work. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I think somewhere in the problem description, your problem got lost. If I get what you're trying to do, as you said only wanted to remove `?action=` which would leave just the `param` so you can use a URL like this

```
http://domain.com/param
```

If that is what you are looking for. Try this rule.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /?action=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: thanks for the reply's. I tried to implement this method but i already got some rules. And if these new methods im getting errors
#turn on url rewriting 
RewriteEngine on

#remove the need for .php extention 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php


<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

Comment: it worked for me endly.. i deleted the ?action= from my a href and returning clean url's right now

Answer (score 0):

Will remove all query string parameters:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301, L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^action=
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [L,R=301]
```